# Compare two float values

Tags: ruby, floating-point, comparison

I want to compare two floats and return `true` if their whole portion (left of decimal) are equal and their fraction (right of decimal) are both >= .5, or <= .5.

The way that I do this is to cast the floats into strings and tokenize the two portions (whole/fraction) of each by delimiting on `'.'` and making the two comparisons in an `if` statement.

Comment: I'm no ruby expert but in c you do this kind of thing by adding 0.5 then casting to an integral type. Then compare on that.

Comment: brilliant dude. that is the kind of stuff that I can never think of. thanks!

Comment: What makes your issue complicated is that the case "= .5" can both be combined with the "> .5" case and "< .5" case. If it were instead only combined with "> .5", then the issue would be a lot easier. And considering they are floats, I don't think it makes sense to insist on that.

Comment: Do you need to consider the negative cases?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need to convert to a string:

```
def compare_two_floats(float1, float2)
    if float1.truncate == float2.truncate #checks if left side is equal. Goes to else block and returns false if not. 
        float1 -= float1.truncate #now subtracts the "whole number" portion
        float2 -= float2.truncate
        if (float1 < 0.5) && (float2 < 0.5)
            return true
        elsif (float1 >= 0.5) && (float2 >= 0.5)
            return true
        else
            return false
        end             
    else
        return false
    end
end

puts compare_two_floats(1.3,1.7)
puts compare_two_floats(2.3,1.7)
puts compare_two_floats(1.3,1.3)
puts compare_two_floats(1.3,3.3)
```

This is effective enough and it works for me. First, you check the left sides by using the #truncate method provided by Ruby for the Float class.

If the left sides are equal it will continue to evaluate the decimals. If not, it returns false and exits the method.

If the left sides are equal, the method proceeds to subtract the truncated (or left side) of each float, leaving it as less than 1.

You then compare to see if they are BOTH less than 0.5 or BOTH greater than or equal to 0.5.

It returns true/false accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your question so that:

- The "= .5" case is only grouped with the "> .5" case and not with the "< .5" case, and
- You do not need to consider negative numbers,

then,

```
float1.round == float2.round
```